# using a value other than 0 for the startAngle of arc method in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

canvas's arc method has the following syntax:

> void ctx.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, anticlockwise);

I was just playing around with this example **[HERE](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-circles/)**.

and I just changed the startAngle to be `(MATH.PI * 2 )`. Usually people use `0` for that parameter , so what difference does it make whether I use `0` or `MATH.PI * 2` ? Can anybody explain ?

Comment: Both answers to your question are absolutely correct: Any angle wraps around to the same angle after 360 degrees. **Just to add:** If you want to express any angle as its 0 to 359.99 degree equivalent you can "normalize" it like this: `var normalizedAngle = (anyAngle+720) % 360` or like this to normalize radian angles between 0 and PI*2: `var normalizedRadianAngle = (anyRadianAngle+(PI*4)) % (PI*2)`

Comment: @markE thanks for your valuable comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes no difference. They can be used interchangeably if you are drawing a complete circle i.e.

```
2 * Math.PI
```

Answer (score 2):

the function uses the radian measure - this measure 
is periodically to 2*MAHT.PI.

So, it makes no difference wheter you use 0, 2*Math.PI or any multiple of it
(like 222*Math.PI)

Comment: i don't get u , can u be more detailed . TY

Comment: `this measure is periodically to 2*MAHT.PI.` , what on earth does that mean ? :P

Comment: It means that 0 and Math.PI*2 are the same angle in radians. Like hour hand on a clock face has a periodicity of 12 hours. 2Am is at the same position as 12pm. A circle in degrees has periodicity of 360. 0, 360, 720 are all at the same location.

Comment: `2Am is at the same position as 12pm.` ... i don't think so :P .. but i get ur point , thanks !